# first React project - Lights Out game

Tags: beginner, react.js, jsx, state

I am working my way through a React tutorial on Scrimba (I am not finished yet). I got to a certain part that inspired me to try a project on my own. I made a game of Lights Out. If you've never heard of it, it was a handheld electronic game where you have certain buttons lit up at the start and you have to have all the buttons unlit. The trick is that when you turn a button on or off, the buttons surrounding it in four directions will also flip on and off. The game I made works, but because I am still learning React I am almost certain the code could be much better.

What I'm really concerned about is the Playground.js file. I run the setSquares four times. I found that if I tried setting the squares above and below and left and right of the target square in the same setSquares invocation, the code kept adding additional squares beyond the 25 it's supposed to have. It seems like I have to generate a new set of squares to turn the target square on or off, then generate a new set of squares to turn the square above on or off, then generate a new set of squares to turn the one below on or off, etc. I'm convinced there has to be an easier way to accomplish what I need to, but I have no idea what it is.

So with that in mind, I present it to all of you for code review (I omitted the CSS for brevity).

boxes.js

```
export default [
    {
        id: 1,
        row: 1,
        column: 1,
        on: true
    },   
    /* 25 boxes, so 25 ids, rows 1-5, columns 1-5, all boxes have on set to true */
```

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import Playboard from "./Playboard";
import Header from "./Header";
import "./App.css"
import "./Header.css"

export default function App() {
    return (
        <main className="main--playArea">
            <Header />
            <Playboard />
        </main>
    )
}
```

Box.js

```
import React from "react"

export default function Box(props) {
    const styles = {
        backgroundImage: props.on ?
        "linear-gradient(to bottom, #e04024, #fa8773)" : 
        "linear-gradient(to bottom, #A3A2A6, #DCDCE0)"
    }

    return (
        <div 
            style={styles} 
            className="box"
            onClick={()=>props.toggle(props.id, props.row, props.column)}
        >
        </div>
    )
}
```

Header.js

```
import React from "react"

export default function Header() {
    return (
        <h1 className="lato">
            <span>LIGHTS OUT</span>
            <span>LIGHTS OUT</span>
        </h1>
    )
}
```

Playboard.js

```
import React from "react"
import boxes from "./boxes"
import Box from "./Box"
import "./Box.css"

export default function Playboard() {
    const [squares, setSquares] = React.useState(boxes)

    function randomize() {
        setSquares(prevSquares => {
            return prevSquares.map((square) => {
                return Math.random() < 0.5 ? {...square, on: true} : {...square, on: false}
            })
        })
    }

    function toggle(id, row, column) {
        setSquares(prevSquares => {
            return prevSquares.map((square) => {
                return square.id === id ? {...square, on: !square.on} : square
            })
        })
        if(row > 1) {
            setSquares(prevSquares => {
                return prevSquares.map((square) => {
                    return square.id === (id-5) ? {...square, on: !square.on} : square
                })
            })
        }
        if(row < 5) {
            setSquares(prevSquares => {
                return prevSquares.map((square) => {
                    return square.id === (id+5) ? {...square, on: !square.on} : square
                })
            })
        }
        if(column > 1) {
            setSquares(prevSquares => {
                return prevSquares.map((square) => {
                    return square.id === (id-1) ? {...square, on: !square.on} : square
                })
            })
        }
        if(column < 5) {
            setSquares(prevSquares => {
                return prevSquares.map((square) => {
                    return square.id === (id+1) ? {...square, on: !square.on} : square
                })
            })
        }
    }

    const squareElements = squares.map(square => (
        <Box 
            key={square.id} 
            id={square.id}
            row={square.row}
            column={square.column}
            on={square.on} 
            toggle={toggle}
        />
    ))

    return (
        <div>  
            {squareElements}
            <button className="main--button" onClick={randomize}>Randomize</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: `/* 25 boxes, so 25 ids, rows 1-5, columns 1-5, all boxes have on set to true */` is this a stub for some code? Could you include the actual code here, if so? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

### watching UI element state with useEffect

Hello! since you didn't provide further information on css and logic/data I can't provide you a fully working piece of software.

Here https://react-ts-zg2vad.stackblitz.io is the link to some of your code and my implementation of **useEffect** react hook.

// *some documentation of react hooks ( ones I use the most are useCallback, useState and useRef ): https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_usestate.asp*

I used **useEffect** to restrict control of when to run code, made a lot more sense to me once I developed SSR pages with Next.js

```
export default function Playboard() {
  const [squares, setSquares] = React.useState(boxes);
  const [counter, setCounter] = React.useState(0);
  // console.log(squares);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    randomize();
  }, [counter]);

  function randomize() {
    if (counter) {
      console.log(squares);
      setSquares((prevSquares) => {
        return prevSquares.map((square) => {
          return Math.random() < 0.5
            ? { ...square, on: true }
            : { ...square, on: false };
        });
      });
    }
```

in your project, you can use the logic inside squares for example to control and MAYBE delete your need of a second logic (counter)

Comment: +1 Because pepe the frog... nah just kidding, the answer is good enough on its own!

Comment: haha thank you very much friend

Comment: Which bit of this answer actually _review_ the presented code.  You seem to have posted an alternative solution, without any review.